# How can I write a formula that shows distinct values in a date range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on a spreadsheet that lists every time a student interacts with our service. In column F we list the student ID number. I need to know how many different (distinct) students we have interacted with in different date ranges. The spreadsheet has lots of blanks due to students being unwilling to give us their ID number.

Currently I have the formula:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(F2:F10000,F2:F10000)>0,1))
```

I need to add a date range to this. Start date is currently in AB3 and end date is AC3. Dates we interacted with students are currently listed in M column. I cannot type the date range directly into the formula as this is going to be used by people with limited computer literacy (even more limited than me) and so it needs to be set up so they do not have to touch the formulas at all.

Data is set out like image below. We often get multiple students with the same name so we rely on ID numbers. The actual number of lines of data is in the thousands. Obviously, data in image is fake but hopefully it will give you some idea. The formulas start after AB and the only thing that is changed is the date range we want to see.
[Image of data layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWSLZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What version of excel do you use? Also add a sample of your data.

Comment: I'm on a Mac using version 16.39. Annoyingly I cannot add a sample of data due to GDPR rules. The student ID numbers are 8 digit codes in the F column. We write the date of the interaction in the M column. The date range we are trying to fid the data for are has the start date in AB3 and end date in AC3. For every interaction in a date range, I've used the formula =COUNTIFS(M2:M10000, ">="&AB3, M2:M10000, "<="&AC3)

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding further information in comments. Comments don't support the formatting options that questions do. If you can't provide *actual* data, please provide *sample* data that is similar.

Comment: There's no need to add "real" data. Edit your question and add "sample" data that can be used to reproduce your problem. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as **text**, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Thanks all! Sorry I misunderstood. Hopefully it makes more sense with the image.